# How to remove the parentheses around the year in nar style?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, formatting

I am creating my document using online LaTeX editor overleaf. The Citation should be like this: `[21]`.

When I use the `nar` bibliography style:

```
\bibliographystyle{nar}
\bibliography{sample-bibliography.bib}
```

I the reference looks like this:

```
[21]  Gallais,  J.  F.,  Kizhvatov,  I.,  and  Tunstall,  M.  (2011)  Im-
proved trace-driven cache-collision attacks against embedded
AES  implementations.  In Information  Security  Applications pp. 243–257 Springer.
```

But I want to remove the parentheses around the year, to make it look like this:

```
[21]  Gallais,  J.  F.,  Kizhvatov,  I.,  and  Tunstall,  M.  2011  Im-
proved trace-driven cache-collision attacks against embedded
AES  implementations.  In Information  Security  Applications pp. 243–257 Springer.
```

How to remove the parentheses around year in the references?

Is there any other style can I use for above citation [21] and reference style?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're using `bibtex`, not `bibLAtex`, right?

Comment: I am using overleaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make a copy of the [`nar.bst`](http://tug.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/nar.bst) file in the same folder as your main `.tex` file and edit it.

The relevant code is the `format.date` function around line `375` of `nar.bst`. The original function is:

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year empty$
    { month empty$
    { "" }
    { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
      month
    }
      if$
    }
    { month empty$
%   'year originally
    {"(" year ")" * * } % TDS
    {"(" month ", " year ")" * * * * } % TDS
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

The line that adds the parentheses to the year is:

```
{"(" year ")" * * } % TDS
```

to remove the parentheses, change it to:

```
{ year } % TDS
```

However, if your bib entry contains a `month` field, then the line that prints the date is the next one:

```
{"(" month ", " year ")" * * * * } % TDS
```

if you want to remove the parentheses from here as well, then you have to change it to:

```
{ month ", " year * * } % TDS
```

which will print as `month, year`. If you want another format let me know and I'll add it.

The function, after the edits, will be:

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year empty$
    { month empty$
    { "" }
    { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
      month
    }
      if$
    }
    { month empty$
%   'year originally
    { year } % TDS
    { month ", " year * * } % TDS
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Just replace that in your copy of `nar.bst` and it'll do. For your convenience, here's the edited version: https://pastebin.com/76Lhhr8U

Test document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{gallais2011,
  author = {Gallais, Jean-Fran{\c{c}}ois and Kizhvatov, Ilya and Tunstall, Michael},
  editor = {Chung, Yongwha and Yung, Moti},
  title = {Improved Trace-Driven Cache-Collision Attacks against Embedded AES Implementations},
  booktitle = {Information Security Applications},
  year = {2011},
  publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  address = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
  pages = {243--257},
  isbn = {978-3-642-17955-6}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\cite{gallais2011}
\bibliographystyle{nar}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image]

Comment: To my surprise there is no nar.bst . I am using online latex editor overleaf to create my document. what should I do ?

Comment: No, there isn't one in your project folder. You have to download the one from [here](http://tug.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/nar.bst) and edit as I said in my answer, OR [this one](https://pastebin.com/76Lhhr8U) which I already edited. After that upload this file to your project folder in Overleaf.

Comment: I have created a blank nar.bst file, simply copy paste contents from your edited version. nothing changed.

Comment: You have to copy the _whole_ file [from here](https://pastebin.com/76Lhhr8U), then upload it to the folder of your Overleaf project, then click the green "Recompile" button. Have you done that?

Comment: @bholanath You're welcome :)